# Unity Could not find any supported Visual Studio installations

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

[Problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U7Vn.png)

> Environment:
> `Windows10 Professional`   `Visual Studio 2017`  `Unity 2017.4.12f1`

I changed the default installation path of Visual Studio 2017 and installed it successfully.
The install path as follows:

`D:\win10\Program\visual_studio\2017`

However, in the Build setting of Unity, it still can't find my Visual Studio 2017.
How can I solve the problem? Thanks~

Comment: are you able to open your scripts using VS2017 in PC standalone?

Comment: yes, I can open my scripts using VS2017, but still exist this problem. How can i solve this problem, thanks~

Comment: Which Visual Studio components are installed? I think you need "Game Development tools for Unity", and "UWP build tools" or something along those lines. Also, note that you shouldn't install the Unity workload as part of the Visual Studio installation, and instead download/install Unity directly.

Comment: @Jethro  Yes, I have install the VS2017 components of "Game Development tools for Unity" and "UWP build tools. As you say, I download and installed Unity directly. However, it still exists this problem, how can i solve this problem? Thanks~

Comment: @killer_mech Do you have any idea to help me solve this problem? Thanks~

Comment: @SmileLing I'm not entirely certain but I can think of two ways only. 1) Some environment variable in VS is not present in system when you selected the same path. So you will have to check what was the missing variable. 2) ReInstall fresh in C drive as I also faced lots of bugs because of installation in D drive of VS for my C++ projects as some of them couldn't compile so I had to install in C. I did checked if something similer situation arises in my Unity but for me it seems not happening. Because of my installation of VS in c drive. I'm fairly certain its related to install path.

Comment: @killer_mech I reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 on the C drive and reinstalled Unity, but this problem still exists.

Comment: @SmileLing I think you better check on with MSDN forums then because I doubt you will get any help here as this issue seems to be related to VS only someone who has extensive knowledge of environment variables related to VS be able to help

Comment: @killer_mech Thank you very much! I will check on with MSDN forums. Thanks a lot！

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit > Preferences, and select your Visual Studio to be the preferred external editor. Use Browse if Visual Studio is not listed. More info [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install windows 10 SDK
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a third answer. I just bumped in to this, and checked that yes VS was the preferred editor, so I went to open up VS to try uninstalling and reinstalling the GameDevWithUnity workflow, but VS popped up a dialog saying I needed to reboot my computer before installation could complete.  So it seems like VS was stuck in the middle of an upgrade, which makes it reasonable that Unity couldn't find an appropriate version.  I rebooted and everyone is happy.